# mongoose overwrite field on update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem trying to update a user with a new profile, mongoose overwrites the previous ones, so it is only allowing them to have 1 profile.

I have in a user document with its associated profiles, buyer or seller with some data of each profile such as id and reputation.
At the beginning the user has no profiles, when I add his buyer or seller profile, there is no drama, but when I try to add the other profile, he writes the one he was on.

At this moment I have this to add the profile (the seller is the same, just change buyer for seller):

```
const user = await User.findOne({_id: 'userId'});

const updatedUser = await user.updateOne({
    profiles: {
        buyer: {
            _id: buyerId,
            reputation: 50
        }
    }
});
```

What he does is write to me the one who is already there, and I understand that I am stupidly telling him that by passing that object, but I tried anyway.

I was checking and I saw that they put a $ set, so I tried it like this:

```
const user = await User.findOne({_id: 'userId'});
const updatedUser = await user.updateOne({
    profiles: {
        $set: {
            buyer: {
                _id: buyerId,
                reputation: 50
            }
        }
    }
});
```

that is not supposed to write me over, and only add the field if it does not exist and leave the other there, quiet (it is what I want).
But the only thing I achieved was that I was writing profiles with an empty object, without any profile.

What I am looking for is that the user is left with the profiles placed there, in profiles, like this:

```
profiles: {
    buyer: {
        _id: 'fuckinid1',
        reputation: 50
    },
    seller: {
        _id: 'fuckinid2',
        reputation: 50
    },
}
```

my schema is this:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String },
    name : { type: String },
    surname : { type: String },
    email : { type: String, lowercase: true },
    profiles : {
        buyer: {
            _id : String,
            reputation: Number
        },
        seller: {
            _id : String,
            reputation: Number
        }
    }
});
```

How can i make this?

Answer (score 2):

You should try like below:

```
 let updateRecord = Test.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: test._id },
  { name: 'Test name' },
  { new: true, overwrite: true }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the more, you should check out the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) for `findOneAndUpdate` options. I also hardly recommend you to use `findByIdAndUpdate` because even if you need to check document on existence, it won't be overwrited without the correct options. And instead, it will create new, if it isn't exist. Also `MongoDB` by default creates an `index` for `_id` field, so your queries will be executed much faster with index, then w/o them.

Also, I noticed that you are using [embedded document structure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/). Well, it's always for you to decide, but I don't sure that you really needed that `_id` field for sub-documents. Anyway, if you need more info about it, just tag me in the comment below, and I'll try to provide more information about it.